# OpenMP and MPI hybrid dynamic scheduling

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp

As the number of threads increase, the count which is "temp" decreases..
When I sent the number of threads as "1" it gives an correct answer but as the number of threads increases, running time shorter but gives wrong answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define MAXITERS 1000

// globals
int count = 0;
int nptsside;
float side2;
float side4;
int temp = 0;

int inset(double complex c) {
   int iters;
   float rl,im;
   double complex z = c;
   for (iters = 0; iters < MAXITERS; iters++) { 
      z = z*z + c;
      rl = creal(z);
      im = cimag(z);
      if (rl*rl + im*im > 4) return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   nptsside = atoi(argv[1]);
   side2 = nptsside / 2.0;
   side4 = nptsside / 4.0;

   //struct timespec bgn,nd;
   //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &bgn);

   int x,y; float xv,yv;
  double complex z;
  int i;
  int mystart, myend;
  int nrows;
  int nprocs, mype;
  int data;


  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mype);
  nrows = nptsside/nprocs;
  printf("%d\n", nprocs);

  mystart = mype*nrows;
  myend = mystart + nrows - 1;


  #pragma omp parallel shared(mystart, myend, temp)
  {
  int nth = omp_get_num_threads();
  printf("%d\n", nth);
  #ifdef STATIC
  #pragma omp for reduction(+:temp) schedule(static)
  #elif defined DYNAMIC
  #pragma omp for reduction(+:temp) schedule(dynamic)
  #elif defined GUIDED
  #pragma omp for reduction(+:temp) schedule(guided)
  #endif
  for (x=mystart; x<=myend; x++) {  

     for ( y=0; y<nptsside; y++)  {
        xv = (x - side2) / side4;
        yv = (y - side2) / side4;
        z = xv + yv*I;
        if (inset(z)) {
           temp++;
        }
     }
  }
  }


  if(mype==0) {
     count += temp;
     printf("%d\n", temp);

     for (i = 1; i < nprocs; i++) {
        MPI_Recv(&temp, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        count += temp;
        printf("%d\n", temp);
        }
        }
        else{
        MPI_Send(&temp, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }



  MPI_Finalize();

  if(mype==0) {
  printf("%d\n", count);
  }

   //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &nd);
   //printf("%f\n",timediff(bgn,nd));
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: the question is why it gives wrong answer when the number of threads increase... for example, if the number of threads is "one".. it gives 1000 but when the number of threads goes up, it gives 200 or 300 when the correct count(temp) is 1000

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining any private variables for when you enter the OpenMP loop.

First off, you must always declare your loop counter for your OpenMP loop (as well as any loop counters for nested loops inside your OpenMP loop) private.

Secondly, you have three variables (`xv`, `yv`, and `z`) that each depend on your iterations in these loops. Thus, each thread needs to have its own private copy of these variables as well. Changing your parallel statement to

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(mystart, myend, temp) private(x, y, xv, yv, z)
```

should fix your OpenMP problems.

Seeing as you say that setting your number of threads to 1 yields the correct answer, I have not looked at your MPI code.

EDIT: OK I lied, I briefly looked into your MPI code now. Instead of all of your sends and receives, you should be writing a single reduce. This collective will be much faster than the blocking communication you set up currently.

```
MPI_Reduce(&temp, &count, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I have another question. Why adding more thread will reduce running time by roughly half but adding more process won't reduce running time as much as Openmp does.. any reason for that??

Comment: Perhaps the overhead of starting up the processes is not worthwhile because of how little work you are doing? Or perhaps the communication you are doing at the end takes a lot more time than you think? I can't say for sure.